# Joomla - any chance to override com_content/models/category.php?

Tags: php, joomla, model, overriding

I'm trying to get a template to work with a sorting menu in Joomla 3.
I'm using the category layout and a infinity load script which is working fine.
After that I made a new menu out of the **categorie_list** module  which adds parameters like this (`?category=your_category`) to the a tag.

Now in order to get this system to work, I need to change the category where the blog view gets its articles from.

I already found the position at

```
components/com_content/models/category.php
```

at line 222

```
function getItems()
{
    $limit = $this->getState('list.limit');

    if ($this->_articles === null && $category = $this->getCategory())
    {
        $model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
        $model->setState('params', JFactory::getApplication()->getParams());
        $model->setState('filter.category_id', '$category->id'); // <- here!!!
        $model->setState('filter.published', $this->getState('filter.published'));
        $model->setState('filter.access', $this->getState('filter.access'));
        $model->setState('filter.language', $this->getState('filter.language'));
        $model->setState('list.ordering', $this->_buildContentOrderBy());
        $model->setState('list.start', $this->getState('list.start'));
        $model->setState('list.limit', $limit);
        $model->setState('list.direction', $this->getState('list.direction'));
        $model->setState('list.filter', $this->getState('list.filter'));
        // filter.subcategories indicates whether to include articles from subcategories in the list or blog
        $model->setState('filter.subcategories', $this->getState('filter.subcategories'));
        $model->setState('filter.max_category_levels', $this->setState('filter.max_category_levels'));
        $model->setState('list.links', $this->getState('list.links'));

        if ($limit >= 0)
        {
            $this->_articles = $model->getItems();

            if ($this->_articles === false)
            {
                $this->setError($model->getError());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_articles = array();
        }

        $this->_pagination = $model->getPagination();
    }

    return $this->_articles;
}
```

Since I don't know, how to override a model within a template even having Googled it, I found nothing more than import it via a plugin.
And that is not what I need and want at all.

Maybe you guys have a handy trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

**1st suggestion**
**How to override the component mvc from the Joomla! core**
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core
**NOTICE:** This method only works if you install and enable the 3rd party MVC plugin - **or provide your own equivalent plugin**. It is fine for advanced developers - just be aware that this is not part of Joomla! Core code.

**2nd suggestion**
Copy the entire core component, hack the copy and package the copy as a new component under a new name (e.g com_mycustomcontent). By doing this you will not have problems with upgrades **unless there is a security issue with the original component**. That means that you will be stuck if you don't know how to apply the updates of the original component to your component.